# How can I fix window size problem on Mac OS X OpenGL/glut?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glut

I printed 4 dots using following code on renderScene:

```
glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
glPointSize(4.0f);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex2f(0.9, 0.9);
glVertex2f(0.9, -0.9);
glVertex2f(-0.9, 0.9);
glVertex2f(-0.9, -0.9);
glEnd();
```

and this shows up:

[four dots show up at corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xv86.png)

[image]

and if I try to draw triangles, 3/4 of it does not show on screen

like this:

[3/4 of screen not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLnNB.png)

[image]

how can I fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the viewport to the size of the default framebuffer. See [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml):

```cpp
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

---

To clarify: `width` and `height` are the size of the framebuffer. This does not necessarily have to be the size of the window. When the display is scaled, the size of the framebuffer and the size of the window are different. You can get the size with `glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)`, `glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)` (see [`glutGet`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node70.html)). Please note that glut is an old library introduced before scalable displays even existed and the terminology `WINDOW` is misleading here:

```cpp
int width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
int height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score -1):

try downloading this fix. http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/glut-macosx/.
Finally add this line to your code:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glutInitDisplayString("rgba double depth hidpi");
#endif
```

This should fix your problem, it worked for me.